# Why does surface tension on ANY body of water seems to have two discrete levels of roughness during light rain?

Tags: surface-tension

Here is a video of a flowing river during light rain. "This two levels of roughness" seems to occur on any body of water from a swimming pool to a large puddle in the street.  Here is a video of a flowing river.  The rough/smooth areas flow along with the surface of the river.  I have also noticed that raindrop generated circular waves travel farther in the rough areas.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG0fneXE0mQ

Comment: This video looks like oil slicks. Oil  changes the surface tension.

Comment: This "two levels of roughness during light rain" phenomenon seems to be ever present.  I'm actually wondering if it is a number of molecules per group phenomenon on the surface of the water.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I only suggest oil. The fact that the regions seem to move with the flow supports the idea that the surface regions have different surface tensions, and there must be some physical reason for this.

Comment: I have recently noticed that light wind can reveal the two levels of surface that seem ever present.   I can't recall an observation during light rain when the two-level effect was NOT occurring.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=10224872686577423&set=a.1206822603687    Here is another example of my statement that the rough-smooth surface tension phenomenon seems to practically always occur.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there are *two* types of waves in a water surface: *capillary waves* in which the restoring force is surface tension and *gravity waves* in which the restoring force is gravity.

They have two different characteristic length scales. For capillary waves, it is of order ~a few inches and for gravity waves it is of order ~1 foot to hundreds of miles.

Comment: Did you watch the video?

Comment: I just can't get over that BOTH rough and smooth practically always appear.  Pool, puddle, lake, river, etc.  There can't always be areas of oil.

Comment: I expect that the reason is something on the level of attraction between and the number of molecules in contact with each other.  There may never be an answer since we won't have images that small.